# Modify contents of table cell using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to write a function that will allow me to change the contents of a table cell. My table looks like this:

```
<table id="stock_table" style="table-layout:fixed">
<tr>
      <td class = "positive">
      <div id="symbol">GOOG</div> 
      <div id="change">+12.22</div>
      <div id="lasttrade">539.08</div>
      </td>
      <td class = "positive">
      <div id="symbol">ANF</div> 
      <div id="change">+4.24</div>
      <div id="lasttrade">63.45</div>
      </td>
```

It's a table that contains stock information and the like. The thing is, prices change fairly rapidly, so I need a way to modify the contents of the cells in the table. To get to each cell, I have the following Javascript function:

```
function goThruCells() {
             var table = document.getElementById("stock_table");
                 for (var i = 0, row; row= table.rows[i]; i++) {
                      for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                           **I don't know what to do here**
                      }
                 }
}
```

I'm not sure how to access each element in each cell. I realize that the table is nothing great, so if anyone has any re-design advice on that I'd gladly listen. If anyone has any advice or pointers, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have jQuery as a tag, but don't use it in your code. Is jQuery an option for you?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? simply edit the numbers and change td's class to positive/negative? numbers based on what, the symbol? also DON'T use the same id tag more than once on a page, it's invalid and bad practice, use class instead

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple IDs on the page, use classes instead.

Comment: jQuery definitely an option- it seems like it would be easiest to do a solution with it but I'm not sure how. I'm trying to edit the change and lasttrade text with json data that I get. I just don't know how to edit a specific area of text!

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to change the div attributes. [IDs can exist only once per page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2); classes can be used multiple times.

Since you are changing your markup anyway, you can add a unique ID to each div, like this:

```
<td class = "positive">
<div id="GOOG_symbol" class="symbol">GOOG</div> 
<div id="GOOG_change" class="change">+12.22</div>
<div id="GOOG_lasttrade" class="lasttrade">539.08</div>
</td>
```

Now you can reference each div individually without resorting to a loop:

```
$( "#GOOG_lasttrade" ).doSomething();
```

If you still need to touch every div, you can use a jQuery loop:

```
$( ".positive div" ).each( function() {
    $( this ).css( 'color', 'red' ); // Insert an appropriate statement here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class instead of ID's as already mentioned. Also your table structure is a bit odd but since you already have that to start with i will not change it. So with the classes instead of id's you would have this code now

```
<table id="stock_table" style="table-layout:fixed">
    <tr>
          <td class = "positive">
              <div class="symbol">GOOG</div> 
              <div class="change">+12.22</div>
              <div class="lasttrade">539.08</div>
          </td>
          <td class = "positive">
              <div class="symbol">ANF</div> 
              <div class="change">+4.24</div>
              <div class="lasttrade">63.45</div>
          </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And to iterate over the table data simply do the following.

```
$('#stock_table tr td').each(function(){
    var symbol = $(this).find('.symbol').html(); 
    var change = $(this).find('.change').html(); 
    var lasttrade = $(this).find('.lasttrade').html(); 
    console.log( symbol );
    console.log( change );
    console.log( lasttrade );

    // to change the value  
    symbol.html( "new value" ); 

});
```

Comment: I like the look of this solution. However, the loop doesn't function quite right- I'll play around with it and post if I come up with a solution!